# How to Customize Time Interval Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Froms PCL Project. I want to customize Time picker with 30 min interval in android and IOS platform.

How's that possible. I am using customize code for Android:

```
public class BorderlessTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetBackground(Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));
            var layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(Control.LayoutParameters);
            layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            Control.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

For IOS :

```
public class BorderlessTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
        Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows an implementation for `iOS` in the custom renderer:

```
public class BorderlessTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
        Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;


        var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
        timePicker.MinuteInterval = 30;
    }
}
```

As you Can see we cast the `InputView` of our `Control` to an `UIDatePicker` and than we have access to the property `MinuteInterval`.

Comment: Please, Can you share Android Code also? @Sebastian Jensen.

Comment: Hello, Is it possible to display only two instance for 0 and 30?

Comment: Hey, Can you tell me that If I want to display only two values rather than multiple time 0 and 30, How's it can be possible?

Comment: For this you have to write your own logic or your own control which handles this. The native `TimePicker` doesn't have this option.